What's wrong with my Python Firebase Cloud Function?
When trying to deploy the function below I get the error:

Build failed with status: FAILURE. Could not build the function due to a missing permission on the build service account. If you didn't revoke that permission explicitly, this could be caused by a change in the organization policies. Please refer to the following documentation for more details and resolution: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#build-service-account

Actually, I can see the function on Firebase Console, but it says "unknown trigger".
I can also see the following error messages on Google Cloud Console:

Build failed with status: FAILURE. Could not build the function due to a missing permission on the build service account. If you didn't revoke that permission explicitly, this could be caused by a change in the organization policies. Please refer to the following documentation for more details and resolution: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#build-service-account You can also view the logs at...


Eventarc trigger projects/myproject/locations/nam5/triggers/sendNotification-xxxxxx for the function was not found. The function may not work correctly. Please redeploy.


Cloud Run service projects/myproject/locations/us-central1/services/sendNotification for the function was not found. The function will not work correctly. Please redeploy.

import firebase_admin
from firebase_functions import https_fn, firestore_fn
from firebase_admin import initialize_app, credentials, firestore, messaging
import google.cloud.firestore

app = initialize_app()

@firestore_fn.on_document_created(document = "users/{userId}/invites/{inviteId}")
def sendNotification(event: firestore_fn.Event[firestore_fn.DocumentSnapshot | None],) -> None :
    if event.data is None:
        return
    try:
        userId = event.params["userId"]
        db = firestore.client()
        user_ref = db.collection("users").doc(userId)
        user_data = user_ref.get().to_dict
        tokenFCM = user_data.get("tokenFCM")
        print(f"user token: {tokenFCM}")
    except KeyError:
        return

I'm kinda copying and pasting from Cloud Functions documentation but still it's not working.
I'm writing more to implement the notification sending, but for now Im testing if the firestore trigger is working (and it's not :/ ).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I figured it after some research. On Google Cloud Console:
1- Enable "Cloud Build API"
2- Enable all necessary services inside "Cloud Build" such as: "functions", "build", "run" and what else you need.
3- Make sure the service accounts have the roles as listed on the following chart (https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/iam):

